# Vagrant Share and local dev domains

Tags: vagrant, subdomain, share, config

How would I go about to share a local dev domain, say myproject.dev, with Vagrant Share? The domain has been set up in hosts to point to Vagrant's default IP address. Is this something I need to add to the config?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quickly share a local domain you can use [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) .
You just have to download and run it then type `ngrok http your-local-site.dev:80`

Comment: I'm doing this now. `ngrok http -host-header=my-local-site.test 192.168.50.5:80`.  That IP is what Vagrant adds to `/etc/hosts`.